# How to design layout with multiple things and borders

Tags: android-layout, android

I am trying to design a sample layout that mimics the User page on Twitter app:

[image]

I am unsure where to begin. So far I have only designed list views or tab views. How can I design a layout with multiple blocks in it (like this sample has 4 blocks) and then further divide them into blocks as well.

If someone can give me hint on how to get started on the first block, I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First block looks pretty much like [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) to me.

Here is some brief explanation how to use it: [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)

The simplest way to tackle other groups ("direct messages", "drafts", etc) would be to treat each group as a vertical `LinearLayout` and have another vertical `LinearLayout` which hosts these groups with some margin between each group.

For the sake of simplicity I would do each group as a separate layout file and do `<include/>` within the top-level layout

Here is what I'm talking about:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/host"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  .....>

    <include layout="@layout/group1"/>   <-- GridLayout
    <include layout="@layout/group2"/>   <-- Simple text button
    <include layout="@layout/group3"/>   <-- Vertical LinearLayout of text buttons
    <include layout="@layout/group4"/>   <-- etc.
    ......

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there an <include /> in android?

Comment: of course there is - [proof link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)